# How does this void function for deleting a duplicate linkedlists accomplish anything? Parameter passing in Java

Tags: java, parameters, linked-list, parameter-passing

So I'm looking through problems in Gayle Lackermaan's Cracking the Coding Interview, and came upon this question:

```
Write code to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list
```

The solution is this

```
public static void deleteDups (LinkedListNode n){
  Hashset<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
  LinkedListNode previous = null;
  while(n!=null){
      if(set.contains(n.data){
          previous.next = n.next;
      } else {
          set.add(n.data);
          previous = n;
      }
      n = n.next;
  }
}
```

I don't understand the point of `previous`; The scope of `previous` is within the function, since it is created inside the function, right? It isn't being used for anything, so why is it there? Also, previous doesn't seem to be moving forward; instead isn't it just being overridden with every iteration?

Also, if I understand Java's passing by value reference style, passing a head node n into a function that does `n = n.next` a bunch of times will not affect the value of n after it returns right? What if the function did a bunch of `n.next = n`, or `n.data = 3`? Would that affect the value of n after it returns? (I assume yes)

I've looked this function for a long time, and I still don't see how calling it will do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line right here:

```
previous.next = n.next;
```

There's magic there, that I'd want to smack a beginning programmer for not documenting.  "Previous" is the last item in the linked list we saw.   `n` is the current item.  So when we set previous.next to n.next, we are **skipping over** n.  This line effectively removes n from the linked list.  It's inside a conditional to check if we've seen that data before, so this is the magic that removes the duplicate.

The reason we're keeping track of previous here is to do that -- link the last thing to the next thing, effectively cutting out the current thing.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. The missing piece for me was that changing previous is changing a reference value, but changing previous.next was changing the value that the reference value "pointed to".

Answer (score 1):

How can you state `It isn't being used for anything, so why is it there?`

See the below...

```
 if(set.contains(n.data){
      previous.next = n.next;  // used here
  } else {
      set.add(n.data);
      previous = n;            // used here
  }
```

`previous` is used to hold the reference to the "previous" node in the list to the current node in case the current node must be removed. This is done by pointing the "previous" node to the next node instead of the current node.

There is no need to change the passed reference because the first element in the list can never be a duplicate. Therefore you only need to remove nodes after the first node. This is done by manipulating "next" nodes in the list not the "root"

Comment: Oh, I see. So previous = n is like setting previous to a reference to Node n. That means that when we do previous.next = something, it's like we're accessing the member instance 'next' of the object that previous is referring to, which changes it outside the scope of the function. But doing something like previous = n doesn't affect anything outside the function, because it just changes the reference value that previous is. Likewise, doing n = node.next a bunch of times doesn't do anything, but I bet if I did n.next = node, it would make changes.

Thanks!